# Nested begin-math symbols

Tags: math-mode, symbols, equations, cases

I am facing a problem while displaying a mathematical expression. The code looks like this :

```
\textit{$f_{1}$} $\succ$ \textit{$f_{2}$} if 
$\begin{cases}
 \textit{dz_{f_{1}}} \supseteq \textit{dz_{f_{2}}} \\
 \textit{outPorts_{f_{1}}} \in \textit{outPorts_{f_{2}}}
\end{cases}
$
```

I am not getting what is wrong in this code. It says `missing $ inserted`. Then I tried keeping the scope of `$` symbols minimal by writing this :

```
\textit{$f_{1}$} $\succ$ \textit{$f_{2}$} if 
$\begin{cases}$
 \textit{$dz_{f_{1}}$} $\supseteq$ \textit{$dz_{f_{2}}$} \\
 \textit{$outPorts_{f_{1}}$} $\in$ \textit{$outPorts_{f_{2}}$}
$\end{cases}$
```

Still I am getting the same error on the lines within the `case` statement.

Any help ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shouldn't

```
\[
f_{1} \succ f_{2} \text{ if }
\begin{cases}
 dz_{f_{1}} \supseteq dz_{f_{2}} \\
 \textit{outPorts}_{f_{1}} \in \textit{outPorts}_{f_{2}}
\end{cases}
\]
```

be what you're looking for? Notice that it requires

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

in the preamble.

You seem to be using math mode in a wrong way.

Comment: Yes, I have used that package. Thanks for the answer. Accepting it as I am using this approach.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, but why are you using `\textit{$f_{2}$}` etc, there is no reason for this at all. Write

```
$f_{1} \succ f_{2}$ if 
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{cases}
   dz_{f_{1}} \supseteq dz_{f_{2}}
 \\
 \textup{outPorts}_{f_{1}} \in \textup{outPorts}_{f_{2}}
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
```

Sorry for saying this, but please consult a LaTeX manual.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I need to go through the manual. I am a total beginner in this.